# bash get the number of files and pass it to for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, leading-zero

I am trying to get the number of files with a certain pattern in a directory and then do a for loop starting from zero to that number.

```
number=`ls -d *pattern_* | wc -l`%3d
for i in {001.."$number"};do
  # do something with $i
done
```

the problem is that my numbers are three digits, so that is why i added `%3d` to the end of my *number* variable, but it is not working.

so if I have 20 files, the **number** variable in the for loop should get a leading zero **020**.

Comment: change `$number` to `$(seq $number)`

Comment: @PS.: Even with that, the brace expansion cannot do variable expansion, it needs to be separate as `for i in $(seq $number)` , also worth adding that `seq` is not `POSIX` compliant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldn't rely on the output of `ls` in this way, since you can have filenames with embedded spaces, newlines and so on.

Thankfully there's a way to do this in a more reliable manner:

```
((i == 0))
for fspec in *pattern_* ; do
    ((i = i + 1))
    doSomethingWith "$(printf "%03d" $i)"
done
```

This loop will run the exact number of times related to the file count *regardless* of the weirdness of said files. It will also use the correctly formatted (three-digit) argument as requested.

Comment: +1... `((i == 0))` here is useless, right? (Unless you have `set -e` set...) Also, `((i=i+1))`` can be shortened to `((i++))`